# Golang: Validate tags at compile time

Tags: go, reflection

I have written a custom tag reader using [reflect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package. Example:

```
type customType struct {
    Prop1 string
    Prop2 []float64
    Prop3 map[float64]float64 
}

type someStruct struct {
    Var1 customType `customTag:"prop1:hello;prop2:0.15,0.1;prop3:0.15=2,3=4.1"`
}

func main() {
    input := &someStruct{}
    tagReader(input)
    fmt.Println(input.Var1.Prop1) //prints hello  
    fmt.Println(input.Var1.Prop2[0]) //prints 0.15  
}
```

The tags are written in a specific format for my custom tag reader. I would like to catch problems (if any) in the `customTag` tag at the compile itself. I run a `make` to build the whole project, so I can also add something in the `make`. Is there an option?

I am assuming there can be a way to check `json` tags at the build time, since it is the most popular tag. So, is there an option?

Comment: No, there is no way to check tags at build time. You can write a custom static analysis using `golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis`

Comment: Tags are not involved in the build process, they're directly copied into the struct metadata for use by `reflect`. As Jim says, you'd need to write your own linter (which is how `json` tags are usually validated).

Comment: `go vet` catches general problems with tags.